# FreeSWITCH call recording not working

Tags: freeswitch

I am trying to implement conference video call recording in FreeSWITCH using `mod_fsv`. I have tried all the methods mentioned [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_fsv). But each time I get the following error

> [ERR] mod_fsv.c:964 You are asking to write 16384 bytes of data which
>   is not supported. Please set enable_file_write_buffering=false to use
>   .fsv format

I have tried setting `enable_file_write_buffering` using `uuid_setvar`, `global_setvar` and `<action application="set" data="enable_file_write_buffering=false"/>` in the dialplan but the error still persists.

I am using the latest FreeSWITCH master repo code.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution finally!

Enable `mod_vlc` in your FreeSWITCH `modules.conf` and compile. After this in your dialplan `default.xml` add the following lines:

```
<action application="set" data="record_concat_video=true"/>
<action application="set" data="execute_on_answer=record_session $${recordings_dir}/${strftime(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)}_${caller_id_number}.mp4"/>
```

The `record_concat_video` variable is required to ensure the calling parties see each others video.

There is an open issue in `mod_vlc` regarding audio in the video recording. Currently either no audio or partial audio is recorded. Once this issue is fixed the same settings can work perfectly.